# Django MySQL database error passing database query

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to query a MySQL database using Django. I pieced this code together using several sources. Can someone explain what is wrong with how I am passing the query? I would appreciate suggestions or links about how to improve my code as well since I'm new to Python and Django. The error I get is:

```
TypeError: query() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

My class: (does database connection and displays result in a view)

```
from helloservice.models import Snippet
from helloservice.serializers import SnippetSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from helloservice.serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import permissions
from helloservice.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework import renderers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

#sudo pip install MySQL-python
class DbConn():
    hostname = 'jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306'
    username = 'rrrr'
    password = 'xxxx'
    database = 'yyyy'

    def query(q):
        myConnection = MySQLdb.connect( host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database )
        cur=conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(q)
        return cur

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    conn= DbConn()
    cur=conn.query('SELECT * FROM pulse.customer WHERE userId = 103')
    #return cur.objects.values_list('loginName')
    print(cur.objects.values_list('loginName'))
```

Comment: Don't do any of this. You're using Django; at least use the built-in connection object to run your SQL, but much better use the model layer and don't use SQL at all.

Comment: Im new to django, what do you mean by the built-in connection object? Could you provide an example or give me an idea of what to google?

Comment: Look, how to use Django models and queries is covered [in the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/) and elsewhere in the docs. You should read and follow that, rather than "piecing it together" from random sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance method should always take in self as the first parameter like this:

```
def query(self, q):
    myConnection = MySQLdb.connect( host=hostname, user=username, passwd=password, db=database )
    ...
```

`self` will point to the instance of the class you created.